# Installing gsl on Debian

Tags: debian

I am trying to install [`gsl` on Debian Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/gsl). I do not have root privileges and I need to install it in my home directory. So I ran:

```
apt-get source gsl
```

Once I got the download, I followed the "INSTALL" file, and I went with:

```
./configure
```

But I got the message:

```
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `doc/Makefile.in'
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Ask your admin to install GSL. Your way is just going to produce a mess.

Comment: @FaheemMitha that's much more sensible!

Answer (score 3):

The `gsl` Debian build rebuilds `doc/Makefile.in` itself, so you'd need to do that that before running `configure`. I'd suggest the following, if you want to use the Debian packaging:

- edit `debian/rules`, adding whatever `configure` parameters you need to `CONFFLAGS` ([line 31 in version 1.16+dfsg-2](https://sources.debian.net/src/gsl/1.16%2Bdfsg-2/debian/rules/));
- run `./debian/rules build`.

If you have the appropriate build-dependencies installed, that will build `gsl`, and you can then install it manually using `make install`.

Comment: To build dependency ; sudo apt-get build-dep gsl ; If the package does not exists in the local repository it will return an error code.

Comment: @GAD3R, the OP said he doesn't have `root` privileges so `apt-get build-dep gsl` won't help much :-(.

Comment: @StephenKitt I did not modify the debian/rules file. 

But after done ./debian/rules build, 
./configure --prefix=$home
worked. 

make worked too apparently. Only doing make install I got at some point in the execution: /bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/include/gsl’: Permission denied Is it simply because I have not root priviledges? How can I let it know I want to install it in my home directory in such a way it can create the directory without needing priviledges?

Comment: `./configure --prefix=$HOME` should be enough to do that. I just checked, and on my system performing the steps you give didn't attempt to install anything in `/usr/local`... Strange...

Comment: Actually thinking about this again, since you ran `./debian/rules build` before re-configuring, you should run `make clean`, `make` and `make install` — `gsl` would have been built with a `/usr/local` prefix, that's why it's trying to install there.